# [vert.x]Vertx tcp socket reads partial messages when writing to fast

Tags: java, sockets, vert.x

I am trying to build a real time application that sends and receives allot of information at a time. i have managed to get the Vertx socket server and client working but im facing one problem. when i have lots of data to write at once about 1000 records then the buffer seems to read too fast and partially reads from the message ahead of the current one, so for example if i send two messages

> Message 1 "hello world"
>
> Message 2 "I am here"

then the socket would receive

> "Hello worldI am" and then it would receive "here"

but it should receive these strings separately.  how can i force the socket to only receive one message at a time like the HTTP client does with its `request.bodyHandler` method. Any assistance on this would be much appreciated.

This is my server code

```
NetServerOptions options = new NetServerOptions();
    options.setReceiveBufferSize(max_buffer_size);
    options.setSendBufferSize(max_buffer_size);
    NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer(options);
    server.exceptionHandler(e -> {
        Debug.log("Client exception " +e.toString()); 
    });


    server.connectHandler(socket -> {
        socket.exceptionHandler(e -> {
            Debug.log("Client socket exception " + e.toString());
        });
        String host = socket.localAddress().host();

        Buffer totalBuffer = Buffer.buffer();
        socket.handler(buffer -> {
            Debug.log("data ::" + buffer.toString());
            final RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited(delemeter, h -> {
                Debug.log("data SPLIT ::::::::" + h.toString());
                handler.HandleUpdate(h.toString(), socket);
            });
            parser.handle(buffer);
        });
    });
```

And this is my client code:

```
NetClientOptions options = new NetClientOptions()
            .setConnectTimeout(this.connection_timeout)
            .setReconnectAttempts(this.connection_attempts)
            .setReconnectInterval(this.connection_reconnect_delay)
            .setReceiveBufferSize(max_buffer_size)
            .setSendBufferSize(max_buffer_size);

    NetClient client = this.vertx.createNetClient(options);
    client.connect(this.port, ip, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            this.client_socket = res.result();

            Buffer totalBuffer = Buffer.buffer();
            this.client_socket.handler(buffer -> {
                    Debug.log("data ::" +buffer.toString()); 
                handler.HandleUpdate(buffer.toString(), null);
            });

        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect: " + res.cause().getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: So i eventually decided not to use vertx anymore as i couldn't resolve the problem. if anybody does know how to resolve the issue i would still appreciate the assistance for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you don't have a protocol on of of TCP to correctly identify the different messages and it is not related to Vert.x . You will have the same problem with any other client/server.

You need to have a way to identify the messages, for instance

- use length prefix encoding in your messages, e.g the long 11 + "Hello World"
- use a separator, e.g "Hello World\n" where \n is the char separator

This way the decoder can correctly decode the message.

If you look at HTTP/1 protocol this is what it does, e.g a chunked encoded message:

`PUT /foo HTTP/1.1\r\n
Transfer-encoding: chunked\r\n
\r\n
11\r\n
Hello World\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n`

This uses both of the techniques explain before.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is just a misinterpretation of lambda

You just have to replace

```
socket.handler(buffer -> {
    Debug.log("data ::" + buffer.toString());
    final RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited(delemeter, h -> {
        Debug.log("data SPLIT ::::::::" + h.toString());
        handler.HandleUpdate(h.toString(), socket);
    });
    parser.handle(buffer);
});
```

by something like

```
socket.handler(
    RecordParser.newDelimited(delemeter, h -> {
        Debug.log("data SPLIT ::::::::" + h.toString());
        handler.HandleUpdate(h.toString(), socket);
    })
});
```

In the first you create a new instance parser each time you receive a message from socket. The second code you create a single instance of parser that will receive each buffers and parse the blocks correctly.